# Starting Android Emulator is not working?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Can not Start Emulator. How to solve the error?

**Console Error**

[2012-08-01 13:56:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] `'C:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\\find_java.exe'` is not recognized as an internal or external command,

[2012-08-01 13:56:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] `operable program or batch file`.

**Starting Emulator for AVD Android**

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Android'
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jme/toolkit/bootstrap/Container
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Container
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.sun.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Container.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: I can Update the Android SDK Manager and then Help->Check for Updates to update the software. Now I can start Emulator. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the solution?